# Virtual member call in constructor Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constructor, c#-6.0

I know there are so many questions about virtual member call in constructor *(Before marking this as a duplicate)*. And I already get the point, why there is a problem with.

There are still two unanswered questions for me:

Entity Framework 6 wants me to set foreign key-collections to virtual. 
But, I want to initialize them somewhere to prevent `NullReferenceExceptions`.

**Regarding a tutorial example:**

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

definitely they want me to initialize the virtual `ICollection<Student>` in the constructor. 
What I understood from the other Q&As about this topic is, this is only about inheriting. When my class is not inherited, this is OK (not nice, but OK).

(ReSharper is suggesting, to make my class sealed. But eeehm, yeah, than I can't have the virtual members, Entity Framework wants to have? So this is not really helpful.) So for now, I'd stay with the constructor-assignment.

- could this cause me problems later? Or is this really ok, and I can ignore the warnings, ReSharper gets me?

**Regarding C# 6**

I could initialize my list with

```
public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
```

- could this cause the same problems like initializing my virtual list in the constructor? Or does this something completely different (I don't believe)?

**update**

when initialization runs but virtual member calls won't run, would this run?

```
public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {
        Students = InitializeMyListAndDoSomethingElse();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> InitializeMyListAndDoSomethingElse()
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
        return new List<Student>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; };
}
```

Comment: It's initialization, not a virtual member *call*.

Comment: mhh but the problems would stay the same, wouldn't they?

Comment: The difference is that initialization always runs. Virtual member calls may not run base methods.

Comment: @GertArnold updated my question for this case. See *update*-part: would it run as expected?

Comment: The last (C# 6) initializer will assign value to property backing field, so property setter will not be executed at all. If you worry - you can use that (though not a thing to worry about anyway).

Comment: @GertArnold can you clarify what you mean? In general that is virtual member call - call of Students property setter.

Comment: @Evk for the C#6-part, thank you. And I also think, that assigning in the constructor is just calling `set` of the property - which is a member call.

Comment: @Evk Yes, you're right, I was confusing this with initialization.